# When importing page to App.js it shows up blank

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I am fairly new to React Native and am struggling to get this page to show up when importing it to App.js. It was working by itself, but once I tried to clean things up and put the code into its own file and just call upon it, things went south.

To break things down;

- Welcome.js contains the code of a "welcome page" I am trying to create
- App.js is the default file created that basically just calls Welcome
- and GetStartedButton is just the code of a button that is imported into Welcome but I dont think its necessary to provide.

When running App.js I am not receiving any errors, my screen is just white!

Thank you for any help, I appreciate it more than you know. I apologize for my ignorance!
It wouldnt surprise me if it was just another typo.

I am sure my code is horrible btw! Assuming my styles were an interesting way to do things! Learning...

Welcome.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
import GetStarted from './src/components/GetStartedButton';


export default class Welcome extends Component {
    render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.containerMain}>
        <View style={styles.containerClub}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Word</Text>
        </View>
        
      <View style={styles.containerCaption}>   
        <Text style={styles.caption}> Words Words Words  </Text> 
      </View>
          
      <View style={styles.containerBottom}>   
      <GetStarted text='Get Started' color='#E50061' /> 
      </View>
      
     
    
    </View>

    );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    containerMain: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'black',
    },

containerClub: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 288
  },

  containerCaption: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 250

  },
  /* To style the button and positioning*/
  containerBottom: {
    
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 100
  },
  /* To style "Word"*/
  title: {
    
    fontSize: 35,
    fontWeight: "bold",

  },
  /* To style "Words Words Words"*/
  caption:
  {
   
    fontSize: 16
  }
}
)
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
import Welcome from './src/pages/Welcome';


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <Welcome/>
      </View>
    
   
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
   
  }
}
);
```

GetStartedButton.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity  } from 'react-native';

const GetStarted = props => {
    const content = (
        <View style={[styles.button, {backgroundColor: props.color}]}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{props.text}</Text>
        </View>
    )
    return <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress}>{content}</TouchableOpacity>
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    button: {
        padding: 20,
        width: 340,
        borderRadius: 8,
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    text: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 20,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    }
});

export default GetStarted;
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your Welcome component styles. You colored your texts white, so... it is all white.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  // (...)

  /* To style "word"*/
  title: {
    color: 'white', // remove it!
    fontSize: 35,
    fontWeight: "bold",

  },
  /* To style "words words words"*/
  caption:
  {
    color: 'white', // remove it!
    fontSize: 16
  }
```

@edit
Also you did not apply your styles in your App component. It should look like this:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <Welcome/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: So I have updated the code to what it is now and still a white screen... I tried to replace calling Welcome in App.js and put a Text there and still a white screen so now I am just really confused. Even kept the background default and changed the text to black and still nothing.

Comment: I also tried your example you left but I am stuck on nothing appearing now so it didnt matter much:(

Comment: Worst comes to worst I will go back to how I had it with everything working, read some more and try again

Comment: I was also getting some weird file errors when importing the button into welcome and welcome into app while doing all this so I have no idea if it could be from there as well.

Comment: I edited the answer. You forget to add your styles to the View component in App

Comment: Bingo! Thank you i really appreicate that On another note, if you have the time, do you maybe have an idea why my button isnt showing up? Assuming it might be in the button code huh

Comment: Surely it is. You didn't provide your button component's code.

Comment: Okay my code is fully up to date and everything is working but the button! I have edited my post to include the GetStartedButton.js code. If I remove the button import and code the text will render completely fine, When I add the import in welcome.js, things get wonky. I have had some trouble in the past with importing files as well. I can give you the exact error I receive if you need it

Comment: I think your import path is wrong. Can you show me your project structure? Where is GetStartedButtonjs file placed?

Comment: I hope I added a picture of what you needed! Again thank you for the help!!!

Comment: import GetStarted from '../components/GetStartedButton';

Comment: Oh my goodness thankyou. That did it. Do you mind explaining the file path correction? Why would it not accept mine?

Comment: Relative paths. Noted. Looking into them tomorrow! Thank you @MrCoconut, you have been a huge help!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `backgroundColor` to something else other than `white` like

```
containerMain: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'black'
    },
```